# Scikit-Learn - Adding Weights to Features

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, weighted-data

I'm pretty new to machine learning and I have a question regarding weighting features.

I was able to get code running with scikit-learn and random forest. Now I would like to weight certain features higher to give them more importance. The data ranges anywhere from T/F to dollar amounts. Can someone point me in a good direction for this? I haven't been very successful finding examples to use.

Comment: Can you provide more information here? I'm not sure if this will be answerable at present.

Comment: Do you want to reweight the importance of predictive features, or predicted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, it's not a great idea to try to meddle with feature weights - RF (and machine learning algorithms in general) works out the importance of features by itself.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034702/how-to-put-more-weight-on-certain-features-in-machine-learning